# How can I obtain the date and time from a git_time object?

Tags: r

I am using the git2r package, and I wish to obtain the date-time information regarding the repository I am working with.
The code I have used to try to obtain it is given below.

```
> library(git2r)
> repo <- repository("./")
>
> default_signature(repo)
name:  xyz
email: xyz@gmail.com
when:  2015-06-11 16:48:07
> d <- default_signature(repo)@when
> d
2015-06-11 16:51:54
> class(d)
[1] "git_time"
attr(,"package")
[1] "git2r"
>
> attributes(d)
> attributes(d)
$time
[1] 1434021714

$offset
[1] 330

$class
[1] "git_time"
attr(,"package")
[1] "git2r"
```

I am lost from here on onwards. How do I proceed to obtain the time from this seemingly vague time attribute? Or is there another way for me to obtain the time from this git_time object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to a `POSIXct` object like this:

```
d2 <- as(d, "POSIXct")
```

Then you can extract the date and the time as follows:

```
format(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
## [1] "2015-06-11"
format(d2, "%H:%M:%S")
## [1] "13:29:25"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
as.POSIXct(1434021714, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
```

You need to update origin, and tz accordingly.